# What is the meaning of pid, uid and gids in Logcat Message?

Tags: android, android-logcat

I get the following message in Android Logcat
`I/ActivityManager(59): Start proc com.abc.xyz:mnp for service com.abc.xyz/.contact.SomeService: pid=31198 uid=10036 gids={3003, 1015}`.

What are the meanings of `pid`, `uid` and `gids` and numbers in front of them here?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

These are standard Linux terms:

- `pid` = process ID
- `uid` = user ID of the application that owns that process
- `gid` = group IDs of the application that owns that process

Comment: What exactly determines the uid under android? The application? Because every application gets an 'account'? If I write an app with 2 processes (declared in manifest with android:process=":..."), do they have the same uid but different pid? Thanks!

Comment: @JacksOnF1re: "What exactly determines the uid under android?" -- by default, each app gets its own unique Linux UID. "If I write an app with 2 processes (declared in manifest with android:process=":..."), do they have the same uid but different pid?" -- yes.